# Catch db2_prepare generated warning

Tags: php, db2

My DB2 class has a prepare function:

```
public function prepare()
{
    if (FALSE === ($this->stmt = db2_prepare($this->conn, $this->sql)))
    {
        throw new Exception($this->get_error());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Some mysterious query is causing a warning in the php error log:

```
[26-Jan-2012 11:17:32] PHP Warning:  db2_prepare(): Statement Prepare Failed in /<path to file>/Db2.php on line 178
```

db2_prepare is not returning FALSE. Otherwise, an exception would be thrown, and I would get a backtrace.

**Am I am not properly testing the db2_prepare's return value to catch legitimate errors/warnings, or does db2_prepare have a bug?**

This is running on the Zend Server stack on i5/iseries/as400.

A workaround in this situation would be a try catch block that generates exceptions on warnings. Not sure how that would work, and that sounds like another post to me.

Also, @ is not an option here. It's generating a warning for a reason. I prefer not to stick my head in the sand.

**Update**:
I finally tracked down the query. It was a badly formed insert statement. Even though the prepare failed and generated an error, a valid statement resource was returned and the script continued with generating an exception. I was using exec to call the script that contained the bad INSERT, but I did not return the output of the script which is why I never saw the error.

It still seems buggy to me, but I don't have time to pursue it further.

Comment: You're saying it's not returning FALSE, but what is it returning?

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure how to find out. I could var_dump $this->stmt to a log, but the script causing the error runs a ton of queries, and I'm not sure how I would trace back which one is generating the warning. I'm trying to figure out how to generate a backtrace on E_WARNING right now with a custom error handler.

Comment: Found the offending query. Turns out it's returning a valid statement resource, yet the prepare fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking the return, you probably want to compare the [SQLSTATE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.doc/doc/rdb2stt.html) instead of whether the preparation returned a successful resource.

You can retrieve the SQLSTATE in PHP using [`db2_stmt_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.db2-stmt-error.php), which will give you the SQL state of the last execution (if you pass a particular resource, the last execution on that resource).  I believe the only SQLSTATE you want back from a `PREPARE` would be `00000`, which is the code for a successful execution.

If you'd like to output a human-readable SQL Error Message, you can use [`db2_stmt_errormsg()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.db2-stmt-errormsg.php), which will output the SQLSTATE and the corresponding error message string.

Comment: I'd like to do some testing to confirm your answer in my environment, but this sounds like a much better solution. Thanks.