# db2_prepare(): Statement Prepare Failed when binding parameter

Tags: php, db2, db2-400

I am trying to prepare a statement for a table function on a DB2 on iSeries, but I'm getting a db2_prepare() warning. When I insert the parameter value directly into the SQL statement, it works fine.

Here is what I'm trying to prepare:

```
$sql = 'SELECT U8.VALIDUSER(?) '
        . 'FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1';
$stmt = db2_prepare($this->conn, $sql);
db2_bind_param($stmt, 1, 'userID', DB2_PARAM_IN);
```

PHP returns: `Warning:  db2_prepare(): Statement Prepare Failed in...` for the db2_prepare() line.

If I change it to this, it works:

```
$sql = 'SELECT U8.VALIDUSER(\'' . $userID . '\') '
        . 'FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1';
$stmt = db2_prepare($this->conn, $sql);
```

Why does it fail when I bind the parameter, but works when I insert it directly? I naturally want to bind the parameter so I don't have to add unnecessary sanitization for this one situation.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: you can't bind tables/columns, *end of story*. Use a safelist.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, it doesn't look like he's trying to parameterize a table or column, but rather a parameter to a function call...

Comment: @bhamby Look at `SELECT U8.VALIDUSER(?)` and tell me that isn't trying to do a bind. The guy even says that `SELECT U8.VALIDUSER(\'' . $userID . '\')` works. What am I not grasping here?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, if I were guessing, I would say `U8.VALIDUSER` is either a stored procedure, or possibly a scalar function. If I were guessing (I'm not too familiar with DB2 for iSeries, only other DB2 platforms), I would think that DB2 can't figure out the data type of the parameter, and that's why it's failing. OP, try adding a `CAST` around your parameter, and see if that works (e.g. `CAST(? AS CHAR(8))`)

Comment: @bhamby, you should post this as an answer. That fixed my problem.

Comment: I decided to reopen. @bhamby go ahead and post your answer as written.

Comment: @BrianKeller-Heikkila Remember, you can't bind like that. Edit: I rolled back to your original post. No need to mention it's not the same, since the question was reopened.

Comment: @BrianKeller-Heikkila I posted the answer, with a bit of additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, I'm guessing that your problem is that DB2 cannot determine what type your parameter is when it's doing the binding.  If you add a `CAST` around the parameter to tell DB2 what type you are passing, it should work.

I'm not sure if PHP has an option, but in C#, you can pass in the type when defining the parameter, so that might be an option, if it's available, instead of hard-coding the type in SQL.

Check out this [other answer I have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023074/catch-db2-prepare-generated-warning) about how to fetch the "native" DB2 errors, which are likely much more helpful than the ones thrown by PHP. I also have [another answer about `SQL0418N`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381898/how-to-resolve-sql0418n-error), which is probably the actual error you would have received if you were looking at the native error.

Comment: To provide some background of why the data type needs to be known: DB2 uses the number of parameters and their data types to resolve functions, so with the untyped parameter marker it cannot determine whether the corresponding function exists.